# const in copy constructor in c++

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor

```
class x  
{  
    int a;  
public:  
    x()  
    {  
         cout<<"\n\ndefault constructor";  
    }  
    x(x& obj)  
    {  
         cout<<"\n\ncopy constructor";  
    }  
    x fun()  
   {  
      x ob;  
      return ob;  
    }  
};  
int main()  
{  
    x ob1;  
    x ob2=ob1.fun();  
    return 0;  
 }
```

initially, this code gave an error " no matching function for call to ‘x::x(x)’",
when i changed the copy constructor to

```
x(const x& obj)  
{  
    cout<<"\n\ncopy constructor";  
}
```

the output becomes

default constructor

default constructor
still the copy constructor is not executing.... why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932700/copy-constructor-not-called-but-compiler-complains-that-theres-no

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is called copy-elision done by the compiler, and that is allowed by the language specification.

See this wiki entry:

- [Copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)

As for why non-const version is giving compilation error because `obj1.fun()` return a temporary object which cannot be bound to non-const reference, but it can bind to const reference, so the const version compiles fine. Once you make it const reference, it is used only for semantic check, but the compiler optimizes the code, eliding the call to the copy-constructor.

However, if you compile it with `-fno-elide-constructors` option with GCC, then the copy-elision will not be performed, and the copy-constructor will be called. The [GCC doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) says,

> **-fno-elide-constructors**
>
> The C++ standard allows an implementation to omit creating a temporary which is only used to initialize another object of the same type. **Specifying this option disables that optimization, and forces G++ to call the copy constructor in all cases.**

Answer (score 3):

The compiler decided to optimize out the copy construction as it's allowed to do, even when it accepted the argument by const reference.

Answer (score 1):

Temporaries are rvalues and do not bind to non-constant references. So `ob1.fun()` cannot bind to the `x::x(x&)` constructor.

However, rvalues *do* bind to *constant* references.

As for why there's no output: The copy constructor is a special case in the standard, and the compiler is allowed to elide copy constructor calls, even if the copy constructor has side effects. However, the construction must still be valid! Another such example is if you declared the copy constructor `explicit` -- it'd still get elided, but your code would be erroneous.

In GCC you can say `-fno-elide-constructors` to bring your constructor back.

Answer (score 1):

The first error was because it was trying to use the copy constuctor with a temporary object.

```
ob1.fun();  // This returns an x by value
```

Thus when you use it hear

```
x ob2=ob1.fun();       // You are passing it by value which requires a local temporary
// This is equivalent to this:
x  ob2(obj1.fun());    // So it is trying to do a copy construction.
```

Temporaries can only be bound to const references. Thus it fails to compile.

After you fix that problem (with the temporary) it can now use the copy constructor. But the compiler is allowed to optimize it out if it can. It could not optimize it out because it was not even allowed to use it in the first version.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor call was skipped due to copy elision optimization. You cannot rely on any observable behavior in copy constructor such as print statements. If you do want to see output from it, try to disable optimizations.